# Why is Icomoon interfering with FontAwesome?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I use both FontAwesome icons as well as some icons I grabbed from Icomoon. The FontAwesome work just well-- awesome. But, some two weeks later when I tried applying Icomoon font icons, they would interfere with the FontAwesome icons. It caused some of the FontAwesome icons to appear as boxes ([]) as well as all the Icomoon icons.

Anyway, here is a live [example](http://viddir.com). The [] beside "Comedy" is a Icomoon icon, the rest of the []'s are broken FontAwesome icons.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqm4E/)`link`

Comment: Please replicate the issue using JSFiddle or JSBin rather than linking to your own website, otherwise when this issue is fixed your question will become obsolete.

Comment: It doesn't look like your IcoMoon font is working regardless of FontAwesome. I removed the FontAwesome includes and the IcoMoon icons still appear as boxes. http://jsfiddle.net/Tqm4E/2/

Comment: I bet it's something stupid I messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `viddir.com` site, the problem is that your icomoon fonts are returning a 404 error:

[image]

If you fix these 404 errors, I think your icons will then show.

Comment: I changed the url in the stylesheet and head to long format, it seemed to clear it up. Thanks